# Why do I get a spurious ']' character in syslog messages with Python's SysLogHandler on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, logging, syslog

With Python 3.5 on OS X 10.10.4, I get spurious `]` characters in the output syslog messages. This can be seen with the following sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('test')

syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/var/run/syslog')
syslog_formatter = logging.Formatter('[{process}] {message}', style='{')
syslog_handler.setFormatter(syslog_formatter)

logger.addHandler(syslog_handler)
logger.error("Test : ABC")
```

If I run this, I see syslog output like this:

```
Dec 16 12:38:33 mymachinename [76399] Test]: ABC
```

(Note the spurious `]` character after `Test`).

If I change the formatter string slightly to remove the initial `[` character, the additional `]` disappears. However, I wish this literal character to appear in the formatted string (and I have the same problem even if it's not at the beginning of the formatting string).

Why does this spurious `]` appear, and how can I avoid it?

OS X's `asl.conf`, which is where logging is configured, looks like this. I have not modified it from the defaults:

```
##
# configuration file for syslogd and aslmanager
##

# authpriv messages are root/admin readable
? [= Facility authpriv] access 0 80

# remoteauth critical, alert, and emergency messages are root/admin readable
? [= Facility remoteauth] [<= Level critical] access 0 80

# broadcast emergency messages
? [= Level emergency] broadcast

# save kernel [PID 0] and launchd [PID 1] messages
? [<= PID 1] store

# ignore "internal" facility
? [= Facility internal] ignore

# save everything from emergency to notice
? [<= Level notice] store

# Rules for /var/log/system.log
> system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [= Sender kernel] file system.log
? [<= Level notice] file system.log
? [= Facility auth] [<= Level info] file system.log
? [= Facility authpriv] [<= Level info] file system.log
? [= Facility user] [<= Level debug] file system.log

# Facility com.apple.alf.logging gets saved in appfirewall.log
? [= Facility com.apple.alf.logging] file appfirewall.log file_max=5M all_max=
```

I do *not* see the same problem on Ubuntu 10.04, so it appears to be OS X-specific.

Comment: Looks like `Test` is being interpreted as a tag. Could you please show your rsyslog configuration? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce, good thought, but I don't think so, because the error is the same even if I replace Test with any other word. Removing the `:` does seem to remove the `]` also (which makes me think it is related), but I wanted a `:` as part of the message.

Comment: @alexce, OS X doesn't use rsyslog, but I've edited in my `asl.conf`, which is where logging is configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE:

Got it. Fix your formatting string to adhere to BSD syslog formatting:

```
syslog_formatter = logging.Formatter('[{process}]: {message}', style='{')
...
logger.error("Test : ABC")
```

and you get:

```
Aug 23 21:38:02 mymachine [65057]: Test : ABC
```

BACKGROUND/ORIGINAL POST

I reproduced your error on OS X 10.11.6

```
Aug 23 21:10:15 machine-name [64643] Test]: ABC
```

The colon is definitely the culprit. I changed the message to:

```
logger.error("Test  ABC")
```

And then the log entry is normal:

```
Aug 23 21:15:03 machine Unknown: [64701] Test  ABC
```

I think  the colon is being interpreted as a formatting character because you are using the BSD formatting option. From the [BSD syslog rfc](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt):

```
the first character of the CONTENT field that signifies the conclusion of 
the TAG field has been seen to be the left square bracket character ("["), 
a colon character (":"), or a space character.  This is explained in more 
detail in Section 5.3.
```

So maybe the OS X syslog is trying to adhere to the BSD Syslog RFC and getting confused?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I struggled with that for a while. This works. The only downside is that on Linux I now get an extra colon which doesn't match other syslog messages, but at least that looks neater. And I could be platform-specific Formatting code in if I cared too. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I think this problem is really interesting because of all the growing NetOpts tools that parse Syslog messages. You would think that would drive even stricter formatting requirements.